# Printing an array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to print an array (I tried both with a for loop and directly with `.ToString()`), but I allways get a `System.Object` output.

The content of the array is the result of this command:

```
$singleOutput = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem C:\*.txt -Recurse |
        Select-String -Pattern "password" -AllMatches
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
System.Object[]
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

This is the whole function:

```
foreach ($server in $servidores) {
    $result = @()
    Write-Output ("---Searching on Server:---" + $server + "----at:" +
        (Get-Date).ToString() + "----")
    $singleOutput = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem C:\*.txt -Recurse |
            Select-String -Pattern "password" -AllMatches
    }
    $result += $singleOutput

    Write-Host $result.ToString()
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

I also tried with:

```
foreach ($i in $result) {
    $result[$i].ToString()
}
```

Comment: That's an array of objects, all right. Why are you printing it with 'tostring()'? What output do you want? Are you write-object or write-host 'ing it?

Comment: I then add     $result += $singleOutput (declared first $result  = @())

Comment: I am using write-host

Comment: `"$result"` instead of `$result.ToString()`

Comment: Instead of `Write-Host $result.toString()`, use either `Write-Host ($result -join "\`r\`n")` or `$result`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're using `Select-String`, which produces `MatchInfo` objects. Since it looks like you want the whole matching lines from the files you probably should return just the value of the `Line` property of the `MatchInfo` objects. Also, your array handling is way too complicated. Just output whatever `Invoke-Command` returns and capture the loop output in a variable. For status output inside the loop use `Write-Host`, so that the messages don't get captured in `$result`.

```
$result = foreach ($server in $servidores) {
    Write-Host ("--- Searching on Server: $server at: " + (Get-Date).ToString())
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem C:\*.txt -Recurse |
            Select-String -Pattern "password" -AllMatches |
            Select-Object -Expand Line
    }
}
```

If you also need the hostname you could add it with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) and return custom objects:

```
$result = foreach ($server in $servidores) {
    Write-Host ("--- Searching on Server: $server at: " + (Get-Date).ToString())
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem C:\*.txt -Recurse |
            Select-String -Pattern "password" -AllMatches |
            Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},Line
    }
}
```

You output an array simply by echoing the array variable:

```
PS C:\> $result
Server    Line
------    ----
...       ...
```

To get custom-formatted output you can for instance use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
$result | ForEach-Object {
  '{0}: {1}' -f $_.Server, $_.Line
}
```