# Remove new line from file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to remove lines matching a detail provided by me with the below command. When a new file `output.txt` is created it comes with a new line which I don't want to come. Is there a way to remove it in the same command which I pasted below.

`a.txt` has the below content:

```
12345   asd 12-22-2009
23432   vfv 03-21-2019
23432   abcd    03-21-2019
38372   kcdsklfm    08-17-2011
```

```
Get-Content C:\test\a.txt |
    Select-String -Pattern '23432' -NotMatch |
    Out-File C:\test\output.txt
```

`output.txt` (expected):

```
12345   asd 12-22-2009
38372   kcdsklfm    08-17-2011
```

`output.txt` (actual):

```
12345   asd 12-22-2009
38372   kcdsklfm    08-17-2011
```

[image: output file screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` does not produce string output (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39558708/1630171)). You're getting that blank line because the `MatchInfo` objects from `Select-String' are mangled into a string when being written to the output file.

To avoid this behavior expand the `Line` property of the `MatchInfo` objects before writing the output to the file:

```
Get-Content C:\test\a.txt |
    Select-String -Pattern '23432' -NotMatch |
    Select-Object -Expand Line |
    Out-File C:\test\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also opt for not using `Select-String` and do:

```
Get-Content C:\test\a.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '23432'} | Out-File C:\test\output.txt -Force
```