# How to output a whole array at once

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm coding with PowerShell and want to output a whole array at once. Is that possible?

I need to output a SQL table and don't wanna say `$reader[1..20]`

```
Write-Host $reader[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
```

I don't wanna say a number like `$reader[2..3]` I wanna output the whole array at once like `$reader[*]`

Comment: Doesn't `Write-Host $reader` do exactly what you need ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534143/printing-an-array-in-powershell

Comment: Can you simplify it ?

Comment: If `$reader` contains an array of values, then simply typing `$reader` outputs the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StringBuilder`:

```
$sb= [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$reader | % { $sb.Append($_) }
Write-Host ($sb.ToString())
```

Or use the `join` operator. For example, join an array and dump every entry on a separate line:

```
 $text = @("a", "b", "c")
 Write-Host ($text -join "`n")
```

Comment: Hi @LeonBold if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: StringBuilder? In you realization it will be okay for GetFileSymbolsCount function, but it is not okay for this question.

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating $reader?

If you are just outputting to the screen, that is the PowerShell default, so no real need for the Write-*.

```
[array]$reader = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31

# Or

$reader = @(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)



$reader

# Result

0
1
2
3
4
5
...

$reader[3]

# Result

3

$reader[0..3]

# Result

0
1
2
3
```