# How to sort an array in the Powershell REPL in one line?

Tags: arrays, powershell, file, sorting, read-eval-print-loop

Treating a list from a file as an array, it can be iterated as:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words = Get-Content ./sort.txt        
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words                         
Alpha
Hotel
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Golf
Foxtrot
Zulu
Hotel
India
Kilo
Juliett
Lima
Mike
November
Oscar
Papa
India
Quebec
Romeo
Sierra
Tango
Charlie
Uniform
Victor
Whiskey
Alpha
X-ray
Yankee
Zulu
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> foreach($w in $words){echo $w} 
Alpha
Hotel
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Golf
Foxtrot
Zulu
Hotel
India
Kilo
Juliett
Lima
Mike
November
Oscar
Papa
India
Quebec
Romeo
Sierra
Tango
Charlie
Uniform
Victor
Whiskey
Alpha
X-ray
Yankee
Zulu
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv>
```

but how is that array sorted?

The list perhaps a bit long, just experimenting a bit with arrays and lists of data to grasp the syntax of powershell and how to use data correctly.

This data originated on a website, I put into a spreadsheet, then CSV, and am just futzing with the data.

see also:

[Printing an array in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39534143/4531180)

Comment: `Sort-Object` can be used to sort arrays, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes @GuyS that's it exactly.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

per comment from Guy:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words = Get-Content -Path ./sort.txt   
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words                               
Alpha
Hotel
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Golf
Foxtrot
Zulu
Hotel
India
Kilo
Juliett
Lima
Mike
November
Oscar
Papa
India
Quebec
Romeo
Sierra
Tango
Charlie
Uniform
Victor
Whiskey
Alpha
X-ray
Yankee
Zulu
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv> $words | Sort-Object                 
Alpha
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
Hotel
India
India
Juliett
Kilo
Lima
Mike
November
Oscar
Papa
Quebec
Romeo
Sierra
Tango
Uniform
Victor
Whiskey
X-ray
Yankee
Zulu
Zulu
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/csv>
```

which works here.